# Why can't I change second element of array?

Tags: c

```
int main(void){ 
    char * strPtr="Hello World"; 
    printf("\n%s", strPtr);     
    *(strPtr+2)='Z';
    printf("\n%s", strPtr);     
    getch();
}
```

I want to change 2nd element of char array by

```
*(strPtr+2)='Z';
```

Compiler does not give any errors but when I execute , code hangs computer.
Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your code to use an actual array, instead of a character pointer:

```
int main(void){ 
    char strPtr[] = "Hello World"; 
    printf("\n%s", strPtr);     
    *(strPtr+2)='Z';
    printf("\n%s", strPtr);     
    getch();
}
```

and you will be fine. When you use an initialized character pointer like in your code, the string data is "read only" which is why you often can't modify it. With an actual array, like any other array, that is no longer true.

Of course, since `strPtr` is now an array, it should be renamed and the modification is better written using plain indexing, like so:

```
strPtr[2] = 'Z';
```

Answer (score 13):

Because when you declare something like

```
char * strPtr="Hello World";
```

it's actually a `const char *` so you can't modify it.

You can change your code to

```
char * strPtr= strdup("Hello World"); //free it after
```

or

```
char strPtr[30] = {0};
strncpy(strPtr, "Hello World", 11);
```

and your code will be working

Comment: It's however nice that even with -Wall some compilers do not see the need to flag this implicit const declaration with a warning

Comment: If you use g++ on linux even without any flag you get a warning

Comment: I tested with GCC 4.4.5 which happily ignories this issue with -Wall ... hence the "some compilers" ;)

Comment: On gcc you can try the  -Wwrite-strings flag

Comment: I find it strange that -Wall does not include -Wwrite-strings

Answer (score 2):

strPtr points to staic memory address, as "Hello World" is part of your binary. You are trying the change the "Hello World" string, which is not permissiable.

you can do

```
char strPtr[30] = {0};
memcpy (str, "hello World",11);
*(strPtr+2)='Z';
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `strPtr` is a `const char *`. If you need to change an element of this array, you should allocate it on the heap, like this:

```
int main(void){

    char * strPtr= malloc(sizeof("Hello World") + 1);
    strncpy(strPtr, "Hello World", sizeof("Hello World") + 1);
    printf("\n%s", strPtr);     
    *(strPtr+2)='Z';
    printf("\n%s", strPtr);     
    getch();
    free(strptr); // don't forget to free it !
}
```

Comment: `strdup()` it's not that portable, POSIX. Seeing the `getch()` function makes me think he is on MS Windows. :)

Comment: OOps that was intense. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Because you are declaring a const pointer, here memory is not being allocated to heap. Memory must be allocated to heap so that you can modify them:

```
char * strPtr="Hello World";
```

Use `malloc` or `strdup` as suggested by Alexis

This should also work:

```
char strPtr[]= "Hello world";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure memory can be modified on the stack too.

Comment: @Armin yeah, but dynamic variables are allocated at heap.

Comment: I don't see any variables using dynamic allocation in your answer.